# How to query CVS for "what have I committed to module M branch B in the last D days?"

Tags: cvs

How to query CVS for "what have I committed to module M branch B in the last D days?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me with a test repository:

```
# your args:  B=branch tag
#             |      D=days
#             |      |       M=module
#             |      |       |
cvs rlog -S -rB -d'>-D days' M
```

You would probably want to filter or reformat the report - depends what you're looking for.

*Based on [Cederqvist](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.11.23/cvs_16.html#SEC150).*

Comment: Thanks, this worked: cvs rlog -S -t -d ">1 weeks ago" APACHEHTTPD

Comment: One more thing.  It logged extraneous statements that would be nice to filter out, ie:

cvs rlog: Logging APACHEHTTPD/Deploy
cvs rlog: Logging APACHEHTTPD/Deploy/bin
cvs rlog: Logging APACHEHTTPD/Deploy/bin/iconv
...
cvs rlog: Logging APACHEHTTPD/Deploy/bin/zip

There were no changes to those directories, and the information is not helpful.

Comment: If you put a -q before rlog then you don't see the extra information.